# Alternative to GLUT

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

GLUT is a very old framework for OpenGL, and there seems to be a lot of negative attitude towards it. I hear SDL is an alternative, though to my understanding it does not handle the 3d component of OpenGL. What is a good option (which preferably has good documentation so it is easily learnable) that can do what GLUT does and provide more functionality, eg. to make a complete 3d game? I prefer not to use pre-made game engines, I'd much rather build my own code from scratch.

Comment: FreeGLUT, SDL, GLFW just to name a few.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

orginal GLUT is very old and I would not recommend it. But the new version of it: http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/ is quite interesting framework. Is is as simple as GLUT but adds more features: mouse scroll, new geometry objects, etc, etc.

last version of this library is from January 2012

here is a useful link with several frameworks for opengl: http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/windowtoolkits/

If you want to make w "whole" project I suggest combining more libraries:

- http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Related_toolkits_and_APIs#Context.2FWindow_Toolkits
- http://glsdk.sourceforge.net/docs/html/index.html
- SOIL for texture loading

Answer (score 3):

If you are to use modern OpenGL GLFW is the best option out there to manage context, window creation, user input. The lib is very active with constant new releases.
Just wanted to add that my consideration to move from GLUT and from FREEGLUT was the lack of ability to define color, stencil, depth bits and MSAA samples for created context. GLFW allows you doing this.

Answer (score 2):

SDL can create windows with OpenGL context (see the `SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL` [window flag](http://wiki.libsdl.org/moin.cgi/SDL_WindowFlags)), so you can use the OpenGL functions. So can [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/), and probably [Allegro](http://alleg.sourceforge.net/) too.

I personally recommend SFML, especially version 2 (which is in development), as I find it very easy to set-up and start using, both generally and for OpenGL.